# Как исполняется код программы?

Tags: c++, безопасность, железо, ос

Начав читать книжку "Operating System Concepts" (динозавры), первая глава познакомила с такой вещью как hardware interrupt, из чего родился объёмный вопрос, который я разобью на несколько частей:

1. Что происходит (детально) после запуска скомпиллированного кода (на С++)? У нас имелся файл расширения .exe на нашем устройстве non-volatile memory, по которому мы щёлкнули дважды - какая последовательность действий ОС и hardware следует за этим?
2. Каким образом ОС контроллирует процесс исполнения программы? Например, каким именно образом она запрещает нам изменять значения байтов в volatile memory, в которых в данный момент хранится работающее ядро ОС, не даёт вмешиваться в исполнение других программ, или же не даёт получить доступ к разделам volatile memory, которые защищены (допустим программа запускается от лица посетителя, и не имеет доступа к разделам диска, на которых хранятся данные админа)
3. Если во время работы появляются ошибки, то как они обрабатываются? Например, если в коде программы появилась строка в духе `1 FDIV 0`, (очевидно вместо 1 и 0 должны стоять адреса переменных, содержащих данные значения), то исключение будет сгенерировано ОС, и данный код не попадёт в ЦПУ, или же ЦПУ (выполняющее данный участок кода ядро) выбросит event-vector interrupt с кодом 0 (divide error)?

Заранее прошу прощения за все неточности и ошибки по ходу вопроса и прошу меня поправлять, т.к. по незнанию могу нести ересь. Спасибо.

Comment: Вам надо почитать книги по процессорам, особенно по защищенному режиму. Потому что на 2 и 3 ваши вопросы ответ один - все это выполняет процессор, ядро ОС так глубоко за исполнением не следит, оно прерывание только поймает если программа делает то, что ей не следует и примет меры

Comment: А по первому вопросу, ОС прочитает exe файл, из заголовков поймет что и как надо загрузить, загрузит, подстроит адреса по таблице перемещения и передаст управление в указанную точку в сегменте кода программы. Ну конечно помимо этого выполнит еще кучу работы, вроде подготовки стандартных файловых дескрипторов, переменных окружения и т.п.

Comment: @Mike В моём представлении процессор - это безумно сложный набор логических вентилей, организованных в общую структуру, но при этом сам по себе довольно туповатый, самое интеллектуальное - предсказатель ветвлений. Он не имеет постоянной памяти, лишь вшитый набор инструкций. Как он может следить за чем-то в духе "а есть ли у нас доступ к этому участку памяти", если всё, что у него есть - набор операций, загруженных из ОЗУ?

Comment: Вы все таки почитайте про защищенный режим. Потому что ваши представления как раз не верны. У intel например целых 2 способа защиты памяти - на уровне сегментов и на уровне страниц. ОС только выставляет определенные биты таблице сегментов и/или таблице страниц, которые определяют начиная с какого уровня привилегий есть доступ к этой памяти на чтение или еще и на запись. А у выполняемого кода есть назначенный ему уровень привилегий. И если он недостаточен (слишком большой, ибо ядро с 0 уровнем работает) то возникнет 13 исключение

Comment: Кроме того есть например биты отсутствия, которыми то же может играться ОС, они определяют есть ли данная область виртуальной памяти в реальной. И если нет, опять же исключение и ОС например подгружает память с диска (swap). Но никто не мешает ОС и как то по другому использовать эти биты

Comment: Ну и плюс к этому iopl отдельно так же по уровням привилегий защищает пространство ввода-вывода, что бы не дать программе бесконтрольно обращаться к оборудованию

Comment: Вот например. https://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v06/index.html Замечу, что после 386 уже ничего кардинально не менялось. Да, для 64 битного режима несколько упростили работу, фактически упразднив сегментные регистры, но что касается защиты практически все осталось так же

Comment: А на счет "интеллектуальности" процессоров все в мире ушло уже очень далеко. У современных процессоров imtel, кроме обычно описываемых режимов есть например SMM к коду в котором не имеет доступа даже ОС. Он обычно загружается во время старта BIOS и дальше уже скрыт от всех так, что ОС даже не подозревает про существование некоторой области ОЗУ в которой этот код. И привилегий у него больше чем у ОС. Ну или скажем внутри обычного intel процессора есть небольшой ARM процессор, который работает даже при выключенном питании (если просто на БП кабель подключен) (см. Intel AMT).